# Draw on BitmapSource high hardware usage

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw on BitmapSource.

My Frame source is coming from webcam in Bitmap type. I convert it to BitmapSource, draw a rect and set to Image control source with data binding.

```
    //convert Bitmap to BitmapSource:

    //WinForms -> WPF
    public BitmapSource BitmapToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        var bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(
            bitmapData.Width, bitmapData.Height,
            bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution,
            PixelFormats.Bgr24, null,
            bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height, bitmapData.Stride);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        return bitmapSource;
    }

    //Drawing code:

    public static BitmapSource DrawRect(BitmapSource frame)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(frame.PixelWidth, frame.PixelHeight, frame.DpiX, frame.DpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();

        using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            dc.DrawImage(frame, new Rect(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height));
            //dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 1), new Point(0, 0), new Point(frame.Width, frame.Height));
            dc.DrawRectangle(null, new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100));
        }

        rtb.Render(dv);
        rtb.Freeze();

        return rtb;
    }
```

my hardware usage results:

CPU: 24%
GPU: 5.4%

on Intel Core i7-4900MQ @ 2.8Ghz; 4core; 8thread
 / NVIDIA Quadro K2100M

The result video is not smooth, little bit slow.

Has someone's any idea how can i make fastest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a [System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2) to [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [System.Windows.Media.ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=netframework-4.7.2) (baseclass)
is very easy but you've to be careful.

First and all you need to dispose your System.Drawing.Bitmap everytime you're done using it. This way you make free space in your memory

Convertion can be done in 2 ways. Using the GDI or memorystream.
Personally I prefer the GDI way. Also GDI will let you use the GPU instead of the CPU. Which is what you want if you're going to render visuals.

**MEMORY STREAM WAY**

```
 public static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource ToImageSource2(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            stream.Position = 0;
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage result = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            result.BeginInit();
            result.CacheOption = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            result.StreamSource = stream;
            result.EndInit();
            result.Freeze();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**GDI WAY**

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);
public static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource ToImageSource(this Bitmap bitmap)
{
    System.Windows.Media.ImageSource image;
    IntPtr handle = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
    try
    {
        image = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        image.Freeze();
    }
    finally
    {
       DeleteObject(handle);
    }


    return image;
}
```

**TEST SAMPLE**

```
        public static void Test()
    {
        System.Windows.Media.ImageSource img;
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"filepath");

        //From GDI
        img =  bmp.ToImageSource();

        //From MemoryStream
        img =  bmp.ToImageSource2();

        //Dispose from memory
        bmp.Dispose();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing nothing more than drawing a border around the image, you could simply do nothing to the `BitmapSource` then in your UI, wrap `Image` by an appropriate `Border`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
            <Image x:Name="Image1" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then see if it improves it somehow, else you'll want to check how and how often you are calling your methods.

Comment: I not draw a border. I want to drawing more rectangles to selecting areas from the image.

Comment: You might want to try WriteableBitmapEx possibly with a custom context.

Comment: i don't want to use third-party library